# C++ scope operator grouping?

Tags: c++, class, scope, grouping

Is there a way to group methods scoped to a specific class, without using the scoping operator :: every time? At risk of arousing contempt in some, I can make a rough analogy to the JavaScript `with` statement; however, here it is used in the source, and not executed.

A simplified example: imagine a `Cheese` class, with the `weigh`, `shred`, and `melt` functions declared as follows:

```
class Cheese {
    public:
        Cheese();
        ... // other constructors, copy, etc.
        ~Cheese();
        int weigh();
        int shred();
        int melt();
}
```

Typically the functions definitions are as follows:

```
Cheese::Cheese() { //constructor stuff };
... // other constructors, copy, etc.
Cheese::~Cheese() { //destructor stuff };
int Cheese::weigh() { return weighed; }
int Cheese::shred() { return shredded; }
int Cheese::melt() { return melted; }
```

Is there a way to say, "Hey compiler, all these definitions are scoped to the `Cheese` class."

Perhaps like so?

```
scope::Cheese {
    Cheese() { //constructor stuff };
    ... // other constructors, copy, etc.
    ~Cheese() { //destructor stuff };
    int weigh() { return weighed; }
    int shred() { return shredded; }
    int melt() { return melted; }
}
```

or,

```
Cheese:: {
    Cheese() { //constructor stuff };
    ... // other constructors, copy, etc.
    ~Cheese() { //destructor stuff };
    int weigh() { return weighed; }
    int shred() { return shredded; }
    int melt() { return melted; }
}
```

Comment: No.  Not sure how that would deal with a templated Cheese, even if there weren.

Comment: For what it's worth, I consider this one of the most pointlessly stupid/annoying aspects of C++.

Comment: @xaxxon Why would templates be a problem?

Comment: maybe not.. but really the ability to search for the definition by saying ClassName::method_name is very handy - far more important than not typeing the class name again...

Comment: You could still searchin the proposed system. You'd hit the ``scope::Cheese`` statement in the first proposition; the ``Cheese::`` text in the second. ~kjm~

Comment: @xaxxon If you think that benefit outweighs the annoyance of the current system, then make it a coding best-practice guideline to always use the explicit scoping. Conversely, in my code (and most code I've worked with), a method declared in Foo.hpp is *always* defined in Foo.(something), so there's not much of a search problem.

Answer (score 2):

Other than defining the methods in the function definition block itself (which has various potential disadvantages), no, there is not any way to do this.

At least part of the reason for this is to ensure that classes, unlike namespaces, cannot be "re-opened" to have additional members added.

Comment: "no" isn't really answer quality.   It's more of a comment.

Comment: @xaxxon But it's the correct answer. What more is there to say?

Comment: Please further explain what you mean by "'re-opened' to have additional members added.

Comment: @kmiklas See an example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c842cf4e9a9a258). The point is that the class-definition block can only be seen once in a translation unit, whereas there may be multiple blocks defining members in a single namespace at different points in the code (even in different headers). In other words, the namespace definition can be "re-opened". This is why the contents of `std::` vary depending on what headers you include. In some languages, e.g. Ruby, classes *can* be re-opened so that additional members may be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- define the methods fully in the class definition, or
- except for constructors and destructors, use a `typedef` short class name for the implementation.

There are also some less practical possibilities, which include source code preprocessing.

---

Example:

```
class Cheese
{
public:
    Cheese();
    //... // other constructors, copy, etc.
    ~Cheese();
    auto weight() -> int;
    auto shred() -> int;
    auto melt() -> int;
};

using X = Cheese;

Cheese::Cheese() {}
Cheese::~Cheese() {}

auto X::weight() -> int { return 0; }
auto X::shred() -> int  { return 0; }
auto X::melt() -> int   { return 0; }

auto main() -> int
{
    return Cheese().weight();
}
```

---

On a personal note I wish more libraries were header only, with the method definitions in the class definitions. The header only approach can't easily deal with module cross-dependencies, where the implementation of X depends on interface of Y and vice versa, and with current 1960's build technology it can cause impractically long build times. But where the latter problem matters it can be and is often addressed by pouring more hardware on the problem, and happily the first problem is a rare one.

Comment: I'm not sure `X::` is any better than `Cheese::`--the most ugly part of the explicit scoping syntax (at least in my opinion) is the `::`. Maybe `#define impl auto Cheese::` with `#undef impl` at the end of the file, for a Rust-like syntax (i.e. to drive your coworkers who like C++ crazy).